# Unsubscribe from all property change events with Breeze.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze

Following the documentation on subscribing to change events for a single entity is working easy peasy -

```
    var token;
    var myEntity  = ko.observable();
    if (token == null) {
        token = myEntity().entityAspect.propertyChanged.subscribe(function (changeArgs) { trackChanges(changeArgs); });
    }
```

But if I want to subscribe to an observableArray and keep track of the tokens

```
    var tokens = ko.observableArray();
    var myEntitys = ko.observableArray();
    if (tokens().length === 0) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(myEntitys(), function (entity) {
            var etoken = entity.entityAspect.propertyChanged.subscribe(function (changeArgs) { trackChanges(changeArgs); });
            tokens.push(etoken);
        });
    }
    console.log(tokens());
```

The subscriptions are working fine but each of the tokens are equal to the same value

```
    //This works fine
    myEntity().entityAspect.propertyChanged.unsubscribe(token);

    //**This does not work because myEntitys does not have an entityAspect, of course **
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(tokens(), function (token) {
        myEntitys().entityAspect.propertyChanged.unsubscribe(token);
    });

    //This works, but I am not sure why because token was set above to equal a single entity (myEntity())
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(myEntitys(), function (entity) {
        entity.entityAspect.propertyChanged.unsubscribe(token);
    });
```

Is there a way to either unsubscribe EVERYTHING when leaving a view or a proper method to do what I am attempting above?  If I reload the same view again it is double-subscribed to propertyChange events.

Comment: I haven't looked into this in detail yet but why are you putting your tokens in an observable array? Why not just put them in a simple js array?

Comment: I actually did try that but no difference, the tokens are always identical anyway so I just got rid of the arrays and used the same token set from myEntity and just loop over all entities and it unsubscribes.  Doesn't make much sense but it works.

Comment: I have someone trying to repro this now.  Will let you know if/when we repro it.

Comment: Ok if you want I can probably make a fiddle to show how I did it, you guys have spent a ton of time helping us so it's the least I could do

Comment: @PWKad would you please elaborate on what you actually did?

Comment: Actually I have not had to look at this issue in a while - I am not entirely sure if the subscription still returns the same token or not.  Sorry may try to repro again to see if it is still not working as expected.

Comment: Thanks bro.. In my case, the tokens are different.. I had an issue unsubscribing with Durandal deactivation.. Now I got it fixed after upgrading to Durandal 2.1

Answer (score 0):

We were able to reproduce the issue and are investigating the problem.